# Stop subscription when no values returned in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am working on sending reports via emails to users. Now I am able to successfully send this reports my only problem is that for this reports there are times whereby the report shows no values. Now I want to ensure that when a report shows no values, it will not be send out.

I went through numerous forums with regards to this, in most times the solution I found is to create jobs, I have no idea how to go about in doing that.

Please note the I used just a normal subscription not the data driven subscription.

If you have any better yet simple solution I can use please assist. Please take me on a step by step work through in solving this problem.

I will highly appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service agent would be a big chunk of work to prevent the delivery of zero record reports. However, you will need to use a data-driven subscription to achieve your needs. Essentially, you would scan-ahead in your Stored procedure that produces the email recipient list to check for no records and return null as the list of recipients. I do not think this is possible without data driven subscription.

On a side note, if you are using an email server you could see if it's possible to do something similar on that side of things.

Comment: Hi there thanx for the response, am kind of worried because I have already  used the normal subscription "not data driven". does that mean in this case I will need to redo the process of sending reports using data driven subscription?? thern introduce the procedure to work out the logic

Comment: The data driven portion allows you to defined a dataset to produce the To Field in the email portion. If you already have your report just add another subscription. You will, however, need logic to handle a no-rows situation outside of the rendering of your report. I would add this in the dataset that returns the email list, returning a list only if there is going to be data produced.